# Not all specials characters are replaced

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a question: I tried to replace special characters with php but  not all characters are replaced, my code is:

```
public function generateTitlePage($company)
{
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $search = array('%27', '%20', '%C3%A2', '%C3%AE', '%C4%83');
    $replace = array('', ' ', 'â', 'î', 'ă');
    $company = str_replace($search, $replace, $company);
    $html = '
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">
            Company:'.$company.'</div>
        </body>
        </html>';
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
  }
```

In this example it is replaced only 'â' and 'î' instead of 'ă' appear '?', where is thhe problem, Plsease help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Convert your entire environment to support UTF-8. 'ă' is an multibyte char which obviously is not converted due to some multibyte issues.

Otherwise use the [mb_ functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) from php which are multibyte safe.

Comment: You missed the first part of my answer: as long as the page is not rendered with charset utf-8, the ouptut in browser will be `?`

Comment: My page is converted to utf-8

Comment: When there's a `?` in the page, it's obviously not served (!!) as utf-8

Comment: Any idea to implement this please